# android Link of class XXX failed while launching application

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I know this problem is often experienced and there a lot of post. However after read and try each answer I still have the problem.
I have no problem on my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 but the problem appear on my SAMSUNG Galaxy ACE cell phone FROYO 2.2.1 even if I downloaded the same apk from google play testing.

While launching I immediatly have a warning indicated an activity class can not be found.
 It seems not good and it is ... when launching activity the application stop.

This activity is part of my project and there is no problem with other activity. However 3 other activities lead to the same and they all inherited from the superclass which can not be linked.

Here the code of Main activity which causes problem

```
// Set the listener
        m_gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id)
            {
                final Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenChoiceActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(ScreenChoiceActivity.EXTRA_SCREEN_ID, m_screensIdList[position]);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

I already tried:

- to clean up project
- check all lib in order an export
- Change the order of libs
- make the activity not abstract because it is
- force to install apk in internal memory

I'm now out of ideas

EDIT:
The ScreenChoiceActivity is registered into the manifest

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.blueskycorner.thousandwords.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.blueskycorner.thousandwords.ScreenChoiceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_screen_choice"
        android:parentActivityName="com.blueskycorner.thousandwords.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.blueskycorner.thousandwords.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found the problem. It was inside the code itself. System could not found the ScreenAdaptorActivity class because it implements OnLayoutChangeListener which is only available from API level 11. 
In the manifest, minSdkVersion is however set to 8 which correspond to my cell phone version FROYO 2.2.1. but there is no warning while compiling ...

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Activity is not registered in AndroidManifest file. look for missing `<activity>` entry or verify `android:name` value.

Comment: You mean I have to register a class into the manifest which is not instantiated ? If it is the case can you explain me how do my Galaxy note 10.1 to find it ? Sorry not to give you the class hierarchy, I'm not allowed to provide image.